# How to hit Office 365 API from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, office365api

I am attempting to access the Office 365 API from a Ruby on Rails backend and am having problems.

Whether I use the `ruby_outlook` gem ([github)](https://github.com/jasonjoh/ruby_outlook) or follow Microsoft's [official Ruby on Rails sample](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142), I am getting `401 unauthorized`.

My access_token is being saved using Omniauth and is valid, I checked by pasting it in [here](http://jwt.calebb.net/).

Am I using the correct access_token? It is over 1400 characters long (1442 to be exact). Can anyone show me an example of how to properly call the Office 365 Mail API from Ruby?

Code Example (using Faraday):

```
key = @auth[:key]

 conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://outlook.office.com') do |faraday|
   # Outputs to the console
   faraday.response :logger
   # Uses the default Net::HTTP adapter
   faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  
 end

 response = conn.get do |request|
   request.url '/api/v2.0/me/contacts'
   request.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{key}"
   request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
 end
```

Code Example (using `ruby_outlook` gem):

```
client = RubyOutlook::Client.new

key = @auth[:key]

page = 1
view_size = 30
fields = [
  'DisplayName',
  'EmailAddresses'
]
sort = {:sort_field => 'DisplayName', :sort_order => 'ASC'}
contacts = client.get_contacts key, view_size, page, fields, sort
```

The exact error that the `ruby_outlook` gem returns is:

```
{"ruby_outlook_error"=>401}
```

Comment: When you paste your token in the JWT parser, what do you see for the `scp` claim?

Comment: @JasonJohnston I see "Contacts.Read Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send User.Read"

Comment: Ok. And what about the `aud` claim? What are the scopes you are requesting (the `SCOPES` array in the ruby walkthrough)?

Comment: `aud` claim is `https://graph.windows.net/` . I was going to ask if I registered for the right app, there is at least 4 different places I've found to register for app access. I am requesting `https://outlook.office.com/mail.read, https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read, https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite, https://outlook.office.com/mail.send' but I was also asked to designate scopes when I registered for the app which seem to be taking precedence

Comment: I am also using this an Office365 Omniauth strategy https://github.com/simi/omniauth-office365

Comment: Yeah, that's the wrong scope. I'll add an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch between the scopes in your token and the API endpoint you're using. The scope has to match the endpoint.

In your case, you requested a [Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) scope, but you're calling the [Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations) endpoint.

You should only have to register in one place for your client ID and secret: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. It sounds like you may have also registered an app in the Azure Management Portal (which requires you to specify scopes in the registration itself).

Make sure you're using a client ID from apps.dev.microsoft.com and make sure your scopes are requested as 'https://outlook.office.com' scopes, and you should be good to go.

That Omniauth strategy *might* require that you register in the Azure Management Portal if they are dependent on Azure's v1 auth endpoints. In that case, forget what I said about apps.dev.microsoft.com and instead change your app registration to use the appropriate permissions from Microsoft Exchange Online.

**UPDATE**: Based on your comments, that Omniauth strategy DOES require the v1 Azure auth/token endpoints, so you have 2 options if you want to keep using that strategy:

- Change your code to use the Graph endpoints. You'll need to use the Faraday option above (ruby_outlook is designed for the Outlook endpoints), and change your URL to `https://graph.microsoft.com`, and the `request.url` to `/v1.0/me/contacts`.
- Create a new app registration at https://dev.outlook.com/appregistration, which will create the proper scopes for your code. You'll need an Office 365 account to login to the app registration tool.

Comment: When using the apps.dev.microsoft.com app I get an `unauthorized_client` error when trying to hit my auth endpoint using that omniauth strategy, with the message `*client_id* is not supported for this API version`. I originally registered for my app at http://dev.office.com/app-registration. Where can I find these Microsoft Exchange Online scopes?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. The dev.office.com site registers Graph scopes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So, finally, I won't be able to use the `ruby_outlook` gem with the Graph scopes, correct?

Comment: I've actually tried that second option, that was one of the 4 places I had found to register for an app, that didn't work either. I suppose I'll have to use the Faraday option then, thanks!